# C problems with nested structs (looks like 1 instance is defined without explicit definitios)

Tags: c, visual-studio-2012, struct, unions

I've created struct:

```
typedef struct
{
    short s;
    int i;

    struct Ss
    {
        short s;
    };
} S;
```

and I have an error (VS2012):

```
 error C2020: 's' : 'struct' member redefinition
```

I see that the name "s" is used, but it is in nested named struct, so it shouldn't be a problem. 
 I know that in C11 was intruduced anonymouds structs and unions but in my case it is not anonymous and I have VS2012 which does not support C11.

Another interesting example is:

```
typedef struct
{
    short s;
    union U
    {
        int uu;
    };

    struct S
    {
        short ss;
    };

    union
    {
        int i;
        double d;
    };

} A;
```

and interesting think is that: in VS2008 sizeof(A) = 24, but I have only 1 field defined.
And when I use code:

```
A a = {1, 2, 3, 4};
printf("A.s=%d A.uu=%d A.ss=%d A.i=%d \n", a.s, a.uu, a.ss, a.i);
```

the output is:

```
A.s=1 A.uu=2 A.ss=3 A.i=4
```

So my question is: why is like that, is it correct behaviour?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You first example is not C because the part `struct Ss{ short s };` doesn't declare a name or is not an anonymous member. If VS allows that, then it must be an extension. It should be either:

```
typedef struct
{
    short s;
    int i;

    struct Ss
    {
        short s;
    } m ;
} S;
```

or if you have C11:

```
typedef struct
{
    short s;
    int i;

    struct  //anonymous structure
    {
        short s2 ;
    } ;
} S;
```

In which case the name of the last member must be different.

Just a remainder what is an anonymous structure from C11:

> 6.7.2.1 p13
>
> *An unnamed member whose type specifier is a structure specifier with **no tag** is called an
>   anonymous structure*; an unnamed member whose type specifier is a union specifier with
>   no tag is called an anonymous union. The members of an anonymous structure or union
>   are considered to be members of the containing structure or union. This applies
>   recursively if the containing structure or union is also anonymous.

Which makes this an anonymous structure:

```
struct  //note the missing tag
{
    int name ;
} ;
```